# Heavy updates and deletions within an onFlush event handler

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I want to add a security layer to my doctrine model. To be able to add the permission checks within a doctrine filter on a SQL level, I have to maintain some database tables that contain caches of access control tokens calculated for each entity.

Now I have to update these tables and in some cases I have to rebuild one of these cache tables completely. This has to be done in an event listener that listens to the onFlush event. What would be the best (most performant and reliable) way to archive this?

It is documented how to persist new entities and how to change associations and primitive properties of already persisted entities. This is done by calling computeChangeSet() or recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet() of the unit of work object and by passing each single entity to one of these methods. The whole system must be locked during these updates and although they are rare they should be done as fast as possible. Also I don't know how to remove entities or even truncate a whole table without having to read out all of the entities first.

- How can I remove entities within the onFlush event?
- How can I make mass updates (table truncation and insertion of several hundreds of thousands records) within the onFlush event? I think I can use $EntityManager->getConnection()->executeUpdate() in this case, right?
- How can I lock tables (read) within the onFlush event?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, `onFlush` is very powerful, so you are hereby probably over-thinking.

To remove entities in an `onFlush`, simply schedule them for removal in your listener:

```php
public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $eventArgs) {
    $em  = $eventArgs->getEntityManager();
    $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

    foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates() as $updated) {
        $em->remove($updated);
    }

    $uow->computeChangeSet();
}
```

To handle mass-updates, you could:

- use a DQL query to update entities you want to deal with
- use an [ORMPurger](https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures/blob/v1.0.0-ALPHA3/lib/Doctrine/Common/DataFixtures/Purger/ORMPurger.php) from the data-fixtures library to handle operations such as truncating tables (either reproduce its logic or use a second entity manager with a subset of the available metadata and the same connection)
- as you said, work on the connection directly: you are in a transaction, so it's perfectly safe

Keep in mind that altering state of the database (mass updates/deletes) without updating application-level objects is a risk, so consider clearing the entity manager after such an operation.

There's an entire documentation chapter about [transactions, concurrency and locking in the ORM](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html). As far as I know, all those operations are valid also during `onFlush`.

Comment: Thank you. Good to know that remove() is working within onFlush() and DQL and the locking methods (likely), too.

Comment: computeChangeSet() requires some parameters... Not so easy :D